# arabic echoing substr it gives me ? mark on end of my data been echoed

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php and mysql and I want to echo a part of data from row one

I used the command:

```
<? echo substr($row['text'],0,500); ?>
```

It will get 500 characters from the $row of text but at end  **?**  appears. I am using Arabic text, which may be the reason.

Since the Arabic text are joined with each other may be it's not ended and that's why when it breaks at the time of the join which each other and if keep the join it will be more then 500 characters so I get the gives **?**

How can I fix it so a question mark does not appear at the end?

Comment: Can you try to change the character encoding to ensure it's UTF_8 and then use `mb_substr()`?

Comment: mb_substr() worked for me, lots of thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s definitely a UTF-8 encoding issue. And the solution is to use [`mb_substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead of plain `substr` like so:

```
<? echo mb_substr($row['text'],0,500,"utf-8"); ?>
```